# How to Scan in User Input and Convert into a Gregorian Calendar

Tags: java

Is there any simple way to use Scanner and place it into a variable of type GregorianCalendar or to convert the string into a GregorianCalendar?
Specifically, I need the user to enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy on one line, and a starting and ending time on another (user doesn't have to enter an ending time if the event has none) in the form of a 24 hour clock (eg. 15:30 = 3:30pm).

Anyone have any ideas? All I see online is how to print a GregorianCalendar in different string formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This class is mean to convert `String` into `java.util.Date` and vice versa.

Here's a brief example:

```
//initialize the Scanner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//read the desired input
String dateAsString = scanner.next();
//create an instance of SimpleDateFormat
//MM: month (2 digits)
//dd: day (2 digits)
//yyyy: year (four digits)
//more of this in the javadoc
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
//parse the String as a Date
Date desiredDate = sdf.parse(dateAsString);
//Calendar.getInstance() should return a GregorianCalendar instance by "default"
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//setting the date into the Calendar
calendar.setTime(desiredDate);
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to set the calendar and just need the variables in the type GregorianCalendar? Let me see if I can explain it simply. I have an Event class which has instance variables: name(String), startTime(GC), endTime(GC). I also have a class MyCalendar that has a HashMap with  key(GC) and value(ArrayList<Event>) which will store the dates and events. I realize that perhaps the GregorianCalendars in Event should be replaced with Date types. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: @aurora91 looks like you want/need to define an agenda or something like that. Well then, there won't be a problem with this approach. The only difference is that I'm used to program oriented to interfaces and abstract classes (e.g. `Map`, `List`, `Calendar`) rather than specific class implementation (e.g. `HashMap`, `ArrayList`, `GregorianCalendar`). And yes, you will be better using `java.util.Date` as key rather than a `GregorianCalendar`. Anyway, you already get the `Date` and you can create an instance of `GregorianCalendar` or whatever you need.